# How interpret HTML in IOS app using swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview, uilabel

I'm trying to implement my first iphone app but I'm kind a stuck. I have API which return as one of the JSON's response items HTML content (tags `like p, img, em, a` etc).

What is the best way to interpret HTML content on IOS? I have found basically two possible solutions:

**1) UIWebView**

I have try this and all content is easily loaded. But am not sure if its good way? I guess that every time user open this view all images (`<img src="">`) are loaded from internet (I have no control about downloading and caching images?)? Am also not sure how to style elements in webView?

**2) UILabel / UITextView**

I have tried this also and i can easily remove all html tags but i have no idea how to style text originally wrapped in html tags? I guess that I would have parse complete html a render it manually?

I would be really glad for every advice because I'm not sure what is the right way to continue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I think that the right way is to use `UIWebView`. Because `UILabel` can interpret only basic `HTML` markup and I get more complicated `HTML` code like youtube embeds etc.

You can load easily HTML string using `UIWebView`'s method `loadHTMLString`.

`HTML` content can be styled using local css. You can get path to local css file using:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myCssFile", withExtension: "css")
```

If you have local path to css you can add it to html header as usual.

If anybody know better way how to do this i still would be glad for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Look up **String manipulation in Swift**. It's a very basic way of managing web content but it will give you great control. However i really don't recommend using an API that return html response because "Parsing" it will be very resource(CPU,RAM) consuming. Try an API with **JSON** response. Also if you want to cache. look up **kingfisher** framework.it's really efficient!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do i understand it right that i should alter html string with some styles and than display it in webView? Im actually using kingfisher but Im now sure how to use it on images in html string? I have JSON response but one of the json response items is html content (sorry i wrote it badly).

Comment: What you can do is in the html response. For every tag, see what it is ( img, p , div..) and look for its closing tag. Now you know the type and the content of the tag. Then send it to the appropriate function to render it. For example if it's an image send it to a function that puts it in a UIVIEW and does all the necessary resizing. But be careful that this will take some time to happen. so make sure to do it asynchronously to keep the app responsive :)

Comment: I have hoped that there is something more simple. Thank you for your advices.